# How to sign into Gitlab in a cpp program using cURL

Tags: https, curl, c++

I'm trying to access some .txt files that are on gitlab using cURL in a cpp program as such

```
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
  size_t written;
  written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
  return written;
}

void produceFileFromAddress(std::string address,std::string fileName){

  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  curl = curl_easy_init();

  if(curl) {
    FILE *listOfDeletions = fopen(fileName.c_str(),"wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, address.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, listOfDeletions);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(listOfDeletions);
    listOfDeletions = fopen(fileName.c_str(),"rb");
    fseek (listOfDeletions , 0 , SEEK_END);
    long lSize = ftell (listOfDeletions);
    rewind(listOfDeletions);
    char *buffer = new char[lSize+1];
    fread (buffer, 1, lSize, listOfDeletions);
    buffer[lSize] = 0;
    fclose(listOfDeletions);
    std::string content(buffer);
    delete [] buffer;
  }
}
```

This works perfectly fine for .txt files on web addresses that are on unpassword protected webpages. However, when I attempt to use it for gitlab I just get the output:

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://gitlab.cern.ch/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

I have the username and password to access the webpages on gitlab that I need, but I do not know how to enter it with cURL in a c++ program.

I've managed to create a read only token from:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/?fbclid=IwAR1BA6JYO-SwPK6Mdi66YzB9ZCflWVdxs-kxMFhtYs07S17SO5OU0bbCg1w

but I am not sure how I pass this token to my program.

I have tried putting

```
  std::string auth = "Private-Token: " + token;
  struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;
  headers = curl_slist_append(headers, auth.c_str());
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

directly after

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, address.c_str());
```

but this did not change anything.

Comment: You did see [this section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#authentication) right?

Comment: @DanielB yes, I am unsure how to convert this from cmd line to within my program, with the Personal Access Tokens. I have edited in my attempt at doing so, but this did not work.

Comment: @DanielB actually when I try in cmdline instead just 

"curl --header "Private-Token: <TOKEN>" <gitlab_address>", I get the same output of being redirected

Comment: I guess you’re not accessing an API endpoint then. [Try this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html).

Comment: Hi @DanielB, thanks very much this put me along the right lines and I got there in the end. The problem was I needed to try this address with /api/v4 in it rather than the normal address I would put in my browser